# Magento2 Automatic group change according billing address and VIES/VAT Validation

Tags: php, magento2, billing

I have a problem with **Magento2** when using **VIES Validation** for automatic group change and eventually exempt for VAT.

This error occurs when:

1. I am logged user, and set shipping address without VAT ID.
2. Then in next order step I set another address for billing - and I fill VAT ID field.

After that, Magento2 still takes my old shipping address for VAT Validation and I can't be exempt from VAT.

I've noticed, that new address/or action for changing billing address during order process is saved only in local storage. But magento validate VAT on backend.

Besides that, new added billing address is visible as "shipping" type address.

Do you have some solutions or have you had similar bugs with that module?

Thank you in advance,

Best regards,
Sebastian